# QFileDialog вешает программу на несколько секунд

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, python-2.x, pyqt4

Используя `QFileDialog` в своем приложении на `pyqt`.

Иногда после закрытия диалог вешает программу на некоторое заметное количество секунд.

Сократил код до минимума - безрезультатно:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


def selectDir():
    directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, u"Выберите рабочую папку") + u"\\"


class TestButton(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')

        quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)
        quit.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 35)

        self.connect(quit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), selectDir)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
qb = TestButton()
qb.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если кликнуть по кнопке, и закрыть диалог, то вы заметите задержку.
Сама проблема довольно критичная, т.к. вызывает отвращение при использовании программы

Comment: Не удалось воспроизвести `задержку` в linux, python 3.4.1 и pyqt 4.11.4. В какой версии питона запускает и на какой ОС?

Comment: Неплохо указать ОС в вопросе. И ещё: попробуйте создать `QFileDialog` и уже его запускать, а не использовать `getExistingDirectory`, если проблема уйдёт, значит она в системном диалоге.

Comment: ОС Windows python 2.7. Пользоваться экземпляром QFileDialog тоже пробовал.

Comment: вынести в диалог в поток

Comment: или попробовать QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, u"Выберите рабочую папку", QtGui.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)

Comment: Спасибо! Нативный диалог спас ситуацию.

Answer (score 3):

Из результата обсуждения в комментариях было предложено вызывать диалог не используя нативный диалог, используя флаг [QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum):

```
QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, u"Выберите рабочую папку", options=QtGui.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
```